# Exibe correctly the Validation Error messages Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-activerecord

I dont know but in my view are appears my message but before appear the name of model, in my view i write this:

```
<% @cost.errors.messages.each { |m| %>
<%= m %> 
<%  } if @cost.errors.count > 0 %>
```

in my model write this:

```
   validates_length_of :types,:minimum => 3,:message => "Precisa ter no minimo 3 caracteres."
```

but when the rails detect errors the message appear this:

```
typesPrecisa ter no minimo 3 caracteres.
```

Because what apeear the name of model, types in my view please

Comment: try `@cost.errors.full_message` (or full_messages)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  <% @cost.errors.full_messages.each do |m| %>
      <%= m %> 
  <%  end if @cost.errors.present? %>
```

Comment: You should test `@cost.errors.present?` instead of counting them and compare it to zero (`[].present? #=> false`)

Comment: @MrYoshiji yup, you can do that :)

Comment: Im use this but the name of model continuous appear how im my question please what is wrong please

Comment: @overallduka It will not show name of the model bcz `@cost.errors.full_messages` will return an array. You can check it on `Rails console`